# Macro that only works if the cell range has a 1 in it

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that works perfectly but only if the range has a 1 in the first cell such as the following: Range("E1:E12"). If I want to change the range to Range("E2:E13") it doesn’t paste to the correct cell. The uploaded Excel sheet is the current macro that works but I need to change the range to different cells.

```
 Sub Part()
    Dim SearchRange As Range, _
        DashPair    As Variant, _
        PairParts   As Variant, _
        SearchVal   As Variant, _
        FoundPos    As Variant, _
        NextCol     As Long

    Set SearchRange = Range("E1:E12")
    For Each DashPair In Range("B30, F30, J30")
        Err.Clear
        NextCol = 1
        If DashPair.Value <> "" Then
            PairParts = Split(DashPair, "-")
            If PairParts(1) = "15" Then
                SearchVal = DashPair.Offset(RowOffset:=1).Value

                On Error Resume Next
                 Set FoundPos = SearchRange.Find(SearchVal, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If Not FoundPos Is Nothing Then
                    FoundPos = FoundPos.Row
                    ' find first empty column right of E
                    While SearchRange(FoundPos).Offset(ColumnOffset:=NextCol).Value <> ""
                        NextCol = NextCol + 1
                    Wend

                    PairParts(1) = PairParts(1) + 1
                    PairParts = Join(PairParts, "-")

                    With SearchRange(FoundPos).Offset(ColumnOffset:=NextCol)
                        .NumberFormat = "@"
                        .Value = "" & PairParts & ""
                    End With

                    DashPair.Resize(ColumnSize:=3).ClearContents
                End If
            End If  '15 found
        End If
    Next DashPair
End Sub
```

[excel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDLjY.jpg)

[image]

Comment: If you remove `On Error Resume Next`, does it still "work perfectly"?

Comment: When I delete the line it still works as long as the first cell has a 1 in it. When I change the cell range to E2:E13 it gets pasted to the wrong cell. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nothing in your code is "pasting" anything anywhere. Have you tried putting a breakpoint somewhere in the code (F9), and then stepping through line by line (F8) to see where the code isn't behaving as expected?

Comment: With or without your line of code it copy and pastes (excel sample cell B30 to cell F1). Just tried the F8 and it says object required for line "  If DashPair.Value <> "" Then."

Comment: No. You're **reading** one cell's valuie, and **writing** that value elsewhere. Copy+paste involves the clipboard, and `Range.Copy` + `Range.Paste`/`Range.PasteSpecial` methods.

Comment: See, `On Error Resume Next` was hiding/swallowing this "object required" error, which is the real problem. And now you can [edit] your question to strip all the unrelated code and leave only a [mcve] that reproduces the real problem, and we can answer with a solution.

Comment: Try declaring `DashPair As Range`, since that's what an individual cell inside another `Range` is.

Comment: I'm getting an invalid statement. Are you putting the Error Resume Next back in or deleting it completely? Also, are you referring to the line " For Each DashPair In Range" should read  For Each DashPair As Range?

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` doesn't belong anywhere, remove it. By "declaring" I mean the *declaration*, i.e. the `Dim` statement. You have it `As Variant`, but it has a real type - it's a `Range`: declare it as such.

Comment: Okay, changed to; " DashPair    As Range, _". It's still writing the value to the wrong cell.

Comment: That's where F8/step-through kicks in - nobody can debug your code for you, and SO isn't a debugging service. Place a breakpoint, step through the code, monitor locals and their respective values (there's a toolwindow for that), see if `SearchRange` is returning the expected value, or whether `NextCol` has the correct value when the cell gets written to (it probably doesn't) - then work up to find out how it got that wrong value. Use the immediate pane (Ctrl+G) to re-assign local values as needed, *set next statement* to move the yellow line up and re-run... that's what debugging is.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm running out of time but I will work on this tonight and get back to you. Thanks so much for your help. Nancy

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up the code a little: your issue is with the following: FoundPos = FoundPos.Row as SearchRange(FoundPos) will return the index cell not the cell in the same row

> i.e. E2:E15 => E2 is row 2, but SearchRange(2) is E3

*** Edit ***

Altered next empty cell selection protocol; previous one didn't work as expected

```
Sub Part()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim Cell As Range, Target As Range, arr As Variant

    With ws
        Dim SearchRange As Range: Set SearchRange = .Range("E1:E12")
        For Each Cell In .Range("B30, F30, J30")
            If Cell <> "" Then
                arr = Split(Cell, "-")
                If UBound(arr) > 0 And arr(1) = "15" Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                        Set Target = SearchRange.Find(Cell.Offset(1, 0), LookAt:=xlWhole)
                    On Error GoTo 0

                    If Not Target Is Nothing Then
                        Do While Target <> ""
                            Set Target = Target.Offset(0, 1)
                        Loop
                        With Target
                            arr(1) = "16"
                            .NumberFormat = "@"
                            .value = Join(arr, "-")
                            Debug.Print Join(arr, "-")
                        End With
                        .Range(Cell, Cell.Offset(0, 2)).ClearContents
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next Cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I will test and get back to you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi  Tragamor, vba is not happy (code highlighted in red: On Error Resume 0, not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Typo: On Error GoTo 0 should have been used; this turns the resume next off so any further errors will halt the macro

Comment: Hi, made the change and no errors but it's not doing anything. So I put the line ?On Error GoTo 0 into the immediate window to see what's happening. Message pops up with "compile error". So I tried to solve that but I'm having no luck.

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: Hi, so sorry to bother you but it now says Dim "ws As Worksheet" compile error, user-defined type not defined.

Comment: Hi, have to ask if it matters if cells are located above the range of cells. So if we change the range to say Range("E11:E22") and the cells above this range have data in them does that have an affect on the macro and that's why it's having so much trouble?

Comment: Is this being closed by you?